# Place button on top of widget

Tags: qt, qt4

I have a widget_2 inside a widget . I would like to place a button in widget_2 which appears on top of widget_2 (overlay). It always seems to be hidden behind widget_2.

Appreciate response.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Please, read documentation about layouts in Qt, for example - [QVBoxLayout](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtwidgets/qvboxlayout.html) . You have to set layout on your `widget_2` via `QWidget::setLayout()` method. Then you can add your `button` to layout via `QVBoxLayout::addWidget()` method and button will appear on `widget_2`.
And it seems, that your main widget also don't have layout. This is bad practice, you should set another layout for main widget the same way as explained above and add to that layout `widget_2`

Comment: Thanks for your response. Widget_2 is embedded in a grid layout and the top level widget is also in grid layout. Can I just create a button and add to gridlayout of widget_2 ?

Comment: @user476566 yes, if you add button to layout of widget_2, it will appear on widget_2. And if widget_2 is correctly added to layout of main widget, button should be visible